# C++ / Gstreamer - Using gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta function

Tags: c++, video, timestamp, gstreamer

I am trying to use alternative timestamp with an existing gstreamer based video acquisition code. I am not allowed to post the code and have little expertise with Gstreamer, to provide a minimal example for this case. I am currently looking for a method to use the function:

```
gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta (GstBuffer * buffer,
GstCaps * reference)
```

My code has the following line:

```
std::cout << "Ref timestamp meta: " << gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta(buf, sample_caps) << std::endl;
```

However, this throws the error:

```
'gst_buffer_get_reference_timestamp_meta' was not declared in this scope
```

I tried adding `#include <gst/gstbuffer.h>` other than `gst.h`, but this did not resolve the issue. I also tried reinstalling Gstreamer.

I suspect that `sample_caps` is not the appropriate kind of `GstCaps` element; but I don't think that it should throw a declaration error as it satisfies the `type` requirement for the second argument. Kindly provide suggestions.

**Edit1:**
When I check the version of Gstreamer using `dpkg -l|grep gstreamer`, it returns a few lines similar to:

`ii  gir1.2-gstreamer-1.0                        1.8.3-1~ubuntu0.1                            amd64        GObject introspection data for the GStreamer library`

When I run `gst-launch-1.0 --gst-version`, it returns:

```
GStreamer Core Library version 1.8.3
```

As pointed out in comments, the above function requires API 1.14 or above. But I am not sure if it is referring to Core Library version. My installation command in Ubuntu was:

`sudo apt-get install libgstreamer1.0-0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-base gstreamer1.0-plugins-good gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad gstreamer1.0-plugins-ugly gstreamer1.0-libav gstreamer1.0-doc gstreamer1.0-tools`

I tried running the command with `1.14` instead of `1.0`, but didn't work. Also, `gst-inspect-1.0 --version` returns:

```
gst-inspect-1.0 version 1.8.3
GStreamer 1.8.3
https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer1.0
```

Comment: What version? According to the [public repository](https://github.com/GStreamer/gstreamer/blob/master/gst/gstbuffer.h), you need at least 1.14.

Comment: That's one area I am a bit confused about. I will include an edit in the question explaining it.

Comment: you will have to manually install the latest version of gstreamer (as debian packages for Ubuntu are not up to date of latest gstreamer releases), you can follow this link to install http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/multimedia/gstreamer10.html